# Error in Sqlite while Updating the table using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using a python to update entries in Sqlite table.
The command I am using is:

```
handle.execute("UPDATE RECORD set NAME=%s DEVICE=%s PROJECT=%s IP=%s COMMENT=%s where ID = %s"%(arg[2],arg[3],arg[4],arg[5],arg[6],arg[1]))
```

To this I get am getting an error as:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DEVICE": syntax error
```

I cannot understand what is specifically wrong with `Device`. Also I have checked the variables are as expected. The data base has a column named device and the database can be opened / accessed and edited using this python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commas missing between set items.

In addition to that, instead of string formatting, [pass parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) to prevent SQL injection:

```
handle.execute(
    """UPDATE RECORD
    SET NAME=%s, DEVICE=%s, PROJECT=%s, IP=%s, COMMENT=%s
    WHERE ID = %s""",
    (arg[2], arg[3], arg[4], arg[5], arg[6], arg[1]))
```

**UPDATE**
If you insist to use string formatting, you should quote `%s`: `'%s'`

Comment: Adding commas between columns worked. Now it is giving me an error as "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: john".

Here John is the  variable I am trying to update in column:- 'name'. Instead why is it searching for a column named john ?

Comment: @john, You need to quote values `%s` -> `'%s'`. BTW , as I mentioned in the answer, you'd better to use parameter passing instead of string formatting yourself.

Comment: `SET NAME='%s', DEVICE='%s', PROJECT='%s', IP='%s', COMMENT='%s' WHERE ID = '%s'`